# Excel - finding combined results of row/coloumn

Tags: excel

I would like to sum how many instances person "X, Y and Z" (see row 1) have been involved in task "A,B and C" (see coloumn 1) in excel. The result should be as shown in the bottom. I'm not that familiar with functions in Excel and have tried searching after a function that would calculate this..... without luck....

Help appreciated!

__X_Y_Z

A.1......1

B.....1..1

C.1..1...

B.1..1...

C.1..1...

A.........1

RESULT
A   1   0   2

B   1   2   1

C   2   2   0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `sumifs()` function. Sumif(range you'd like to sum,criteria range, criteria). In your case, Sumif(column values, row names, "A") would give you the sum of all values in a given column that are in a row of letter "A".

See this example: http://www.filedropper.com/example_1

If you have a letter value, you could use the `countifs()` functions. Countifs(range you'd like to count,letter value, criteria range, criteria). In your case, Countifs(column values, "D", row names, "A") would give you the count of all values in a given column that are "D", and that are also in a row of letter "A".

If you simply want to count all non-empty cells, use "<>" as your criteria in your countifs function instead of "D".

See this example: http://www.filedropper.com/example_2

Comment: Thanks a million!!!
Is there any way to replace "1" with for instance a letter, with the same function/end result?